# Mongo read only sync database

Tags: mongodb, clone, mongodb-replica-set, database

I have a replicaSet of mongo running , I just want to have another read only clone of same replicaSet(slave) ,with all the data in it is in sync with replicaSet(master). I had come across a solution available [here](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector) . But could not exactly figure out the way it works . Any suggestion or approach to implement the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a further node which will always be read-only, that means you can't allow it to be the [Primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/#primary). To do that, you need to set the member's [priority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority) to 0; you can also set its [votes attribute](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) to 0 too, if you want to make it completely passive in the replica set.

The documentation describes this method of [simulating a master-slave relationship within a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/master-slave/#deploy-master-slave-equivalent-using-replica-sets).